# Inserting Twillio message history into data structure or text file

Tags: python, twilio

I have extracted my message history from Twillio - it prints it to python's shell. However, I cannot find a reasonable way to place it into a data structure or a text file for further analysis of the messages. My account sid and account token are hidden just for this post. Nothing is written to my txt file either.

```
from twilio.rest import Client
account_sid = 'XXXX'
auth_token = 'XXXX'

client = Client(account_sid, auth_token)

from twilio.twiml.messaging_response import Message, MessagingResponse
from flask import Flask, request, redirect


app = Flask(__name__) #creating a flask app

@app.route("/sms", methods=['GET', 'POST']) #creating an sms route
def sms_reply():
    """Respond to incoming calls with a simple text message."""
    # Start our TwiML response
    resp = MessagingResponse()

# Add a message
resp.message("The Robots are coming! Head for the hills!")
return str(resp)

text = []
messages = client.messages.list()
for record in messages:
    text.append(record.body.encode("utf-8"))
```

My message history:
Sent from your Twilio trial account - Your verification code is: 219042
Test

Comment: Hi Dan, you seem to be conflating responding to an incoming webhook with hitting the API and fetching message history in this code. Also, the indentation around the route and `resp` and then the other stuff seems off too. Perhaps you could reduce the code to just the bit that isn't working right now? Are you seeing any errors when you run the code at all?

Comment: Hi Phil. I have reduce my code and added 4 lines that put the message history into a python list structure. However, when i try to do list manipulation I receive 'TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, bytes found'. My list data looks like this: '[b'Sent from your Twilio trial account - Your verification code is: 219042', b'Sent from your Twilio trial account - Your verification code is:'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

As my teammate Phil mentioned above, you seem to be conflating responding to an incoming webhook with hitting the API and fetching message history.

[These Twilio docs](https://www.twilio.com/docs/sms/tutorials/how-to-retrieve-and-modify-message-history-python) mention how to retrieve message history in Python.

The following code writes message history to a .txt file called "chathistory.txt".

```
from twilio.rest import Client
account_sid = 'XXXX'
auth_token = 'XXXX'

client = Client(account_sid, auth_token)
messages = client.messages.list(limit=20)
writetofile = open("chathistory.txt", 'w')
for record in messages:
    print(record.body)
    writetofile.write(record.body + '\n')
writetofile.close()
```

Let us know if this helps at all!

Comment: The solution works. However I find it hard to understand and implement the Twilio documentation. Would you know how to do the exact above only for what the recipient messages back. Thanks Lizzie. Regards.

Comment: You can also filter out messages sent from a certain number, as mentioned here: https://www.twilio.com/docs/sms/tutorials/how-to-retrieve-and-modify-message-history-python
```
messages = client.messages.list(limit=1, from_='the-number-that-sent-the-message')
```
```